# Why is my memory running at 665Mhz when the BIOS is clearly set to be higher?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I was trying to look for new compatible memory for my computer.  When I noticed my current RAM seems to be running at 665Mhz

My motherboard is a [MSI p67-G45](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/P67AG45_B3/Overview) and I currently have 8GB of RAM, looking to go to 16GB or 24GB.

According to this picture my current RAM 2x4GB (CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9)
are running at 665MHz:

[image]

And CPU-Z agrees with the 667Mhz speed 
[image]

The [documentation from Corsair](https://www.corsair.com/en-us/vengeance-8gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9) says the specs are 1600MHz. It is even in the name. In my BIOS I have changed the overclock setting from auto to 1333MHz and even 1600MHz. No change in the screen.

So is the application wrong or is my memory really running at ~667MHz

And if they are running at 667MHz should I not get these to mix speeds
[16GB Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009YOJZ5E)

Comment: Have you tried a different program.  Speccy is trash software from a known company to distribute malicious software (CCleaner)

Comment: Ouch..  I forgot which site recommended but I have been researching "Identify which memory is compatible with your system"   I used the online crucial one but that does not tell ram speed.  Do you have a recommend program or website?

Comment: You can use anything you want, just use something else, to confirm the results of Speccy are accurate.  I assume, you have selected the incorrect XMP profile, I am just trying to confirm

Comment: sure I just did not come across any other type of program yet, just asking what you would use?  What is XMP profile?

Comment: Do some research.  I don't make software recommendations here at SU.  [Here](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) since you seem lost with a helping hand.

Comment: The fastest your memory will run on your system is 800 MHz.  Use the the XMP-1600 profile.  You purchased memory you would have to overclock your CPU to use at 1600 MHz.  I am guessing you don't have an Intel processor that is unlocked.

Comment: Thank you I had an option to enable xmp - now memory is running at 798.  I  have an Intel Core i5 2500K @ 3.3Ghz.  I don't know what unlock is.

Comment: An unlocked processor allows you to overclock it.  If you can overclock your processor you can overclock your memory.

Comment: Your processor only supported DDR3 1066/1333, anything beyond those frequencies, requires overclocking the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDR SDRAM stands for "Double Data Rate Synchronous Dynamic Random-Access Memory". In contrast to SDR (="Single Data Rate") SDRAM, data is transferred on both the rising and falling edges of the clock signal. This allows for twice the speed at the same clock rate.

In order to highlight this advantage, manufacturers started advertising the transfer rate in megatransfers per second (MT/s) rather than the actual bus clock rate. So DDR SDRAM operating at a 200MHz bus clock speed was advertised as DDR-400 and the BIOS generally mentions that the RAM runs at 400MHz.

This hasn't changed with the introduction of later generations of DDR SDRAM. Technically the actual memory chip clock rate hasn't increased much but the bus clock rate certainly has and manufacturers continue to advertise the transfer rate rather than the bus clock rate.

So to come back to your question. Your RAM is running at 667MHz which corresponds with a 1333 MT/s data rate. The BIOS is likely to mention that the RAM is running at 1333MHz. As mentioned by other people, the memory controller in your CPU officially only supports clock speeds up to 667MHz. Your motherboard will default to these speeds when left at its safe settings.

Comment: SDRAM stands for Synchronous dynamic random-access memory.

Comment: DDR SDRAM stands for Double data rate synchronous dynamic random-access memory. Rest of your is correct just wish the first part was technically correct